# Specifying NUnit version in MonoDevelop

Tags: nunit, monodevelop

I'm running MonoDevelop 2.4. I would like to debug a test assembly with NUnit 2.5.10, but I failed. The Nunit-plugin in MonoDevelop runs a version of NUnit which is incompatible with my tests.

I don't need the nunit-plugin integration; I am after the ability to debug tests, so running the tests with external app (nunit-console.exe) would be enough for me.

I tried specifying external tools, 'Execute' action and other configuration settings but all I achieved was being able to run nunit-console from within MonoDevelop, but the debugger isn't started.

With the 'Attach to process' functionality removed from MonoDevelop I feel stuck (with 'Attach to process' I could attach to NUnit-Gui).

Thanks in advance
Tymek

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following links could be useful for you:

- [http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=13&ved=0CCsQFjACOAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.go-mono.com%2Fmeeting06%2FNUnit_and_Mono.pdf&rct=j&q=specify%20nunit%20version%20monodevelop&ei=LM1OTtSADOPj4QT5_ZHrBw&usg=AFQjCNFEWdRj9FEoB3nQ18YSi1lp9QJnSQ](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=13&ved=0CCsQFjACOAo&url=http://www.go-mono.com/meeting06/NUnit_and_Mono.pdf&rct=j&q=specify%20nunit%20version%20monodevelop&ei=LM1OTtSADOPj4QT5_ZHrBw&usg=AFQjCNFEWdRj9FEoB3nQ18YSi1lp9QJnSQ)
- http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td3007252

Best regards.
Ángel Manuel.